# how to have custom width column in html

Tags: html, html-table

I want to have different num of columns in a html table rows below is the structure which i want to achieve but couldn't succeed yet. Please guide me to achieve this

[image]

```
                   <tr>
                       <td>              
                       </td>
                       <td>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td width="33%">              
                       </td>

                       <td width="33%">
                       </td>

                       <td width="33%">
                       </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>              
                       </td>
                       <td>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
```

Comment: Hmmm... this doesn't look like a table anymore. Is there a valid reason to use `<table>`? Perhaps you should consider using `<div>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This way

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="innerTable" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>50%</td>
                <td>50%</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="innerTable" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>33%</td>
                <td>33%</td>
                <td>33%</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>


</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="innerTable" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>50%</td>
                <td>50%</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>

</tr>
```

CSS

```
table{
  width:100%;
  border:0px solid #ddd;

}
table.innerTable td{
  border:1px solid #999;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8j1ptbty/3/